# Re-bind calendar to get new data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using the "events" elements of fullcalendar to get data dynamically. This works fine and I'm happy with it, however, I need to be able to pass a GET / POST parameter to the PHP page, and I'm unsure how to refresh the call to include the changed variable... My code is like this:

```
function redrawMe() {

    var resource_array = get_resources();

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        "cache"     : true,
        "editable"  : true,
        "events"    : {
            "url"       : "/ajax/get_calendar_entries.php",
            "data"      : function() {
                return  { "resources" : resource_array }
            }
        }
    });
}

function get_resources() {

    let view_id = $("#view_id").val();

    let promise = $.ajax({
        "url"       : "/ajax/get_resources.php",
        "data"      : { "view_id" : view_id },
        "dataType"  : "json"
    });

    promise.done(function(data) {
        return data;
    });
}
```

Tl;Dr:

I have a dropdown ("view_id") that just needs to fire `redrawMe()` and redraw the calendar dynamically.

Currently, I can see in the network tab of the developer tools, that the "events" url isn't being fired, and I think its probably because the `#calendar` div is "already" a calendar?

Make sense?

Comment: get_ressources does not return anything, you should use a callback or the async/wait keywords

Comment: Why not pass "view_id" to get_calendar_entries.php directly, and let the server get the right resources based on that, since you determine that by making a call to the server anyway. It can use the same logic that get_resources.php does to get that info. Then there's one less ajax call and you don't need to start chaining async calls.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "redraw" the calendar? Just refresh the events? In that case yeah don't re-initialise the entire calendar, just call fullCalendar's refetchEvents method . https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/ It'll automatically make calls to any existing event URLs to get the latest data.

Comment: @ADyson - probably will use one ajax call - this is just PoC. I'm looking at the "refetchEvents" currently, but not its not even including the "resources" parameter at all...

Comment: Updated the code in the ticket to what I'm currently attempting!

Comment: Thanks chaps. You both made me re-evaluate and fix the issue. The above code is now the working code. Many thanks

Comment: @Chris don't vandalise your question with working code. Then it's a meaningless question, yet it's still open for answers, theoretically. Instead leave the broken code up there (hint: you can roll back your edits), and post your solution in the answer question and self-accept it. Future readers can then see what your problem was, and how you fixed it.

Comment: However, you shouldn't need to keep removing and adding event sources like this. It should be possible to get the view ID dynamically without doing that, just by calling refetch events, and defining the object you now call `cal_events` as the `events` option in your initial config. Also in your current version, I think it will fetch the events twice in a row - once when you add the event source (it automatically fetches) and then again when you call refetchEvents immediately afterwards. Watch your network tab to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended by @ADyson - I pass the view_id in the ajax call and use that, rather than multiple calls.

function redrawMe() {

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    "cache"     : true,
    "editable"  : true,
    "eventClick" : function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        showJob(calEvent.job_id);
    },
    "data"      : function() {
        return  {
            "view_id" : $("#view_id").val(),
        });
    });
}
```

The above works fine

When I want to force a refresh I use this:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
```